# What's the proper way to run l3build tests for classes?

Tags: documentclass-writing, l3build, packages-testing

I'm (still) in the process of trying to understand how `l3build` tests work, *more specifically for classes*.

For this, I created a `sandbox` directory, the content of which being:

```
$ tree sandbox/
sandbox/
├── build.lua
├── myclass.cls
└── testfiles
    └── myclass-test.lvt
```

This directory structure and the content of these various files may be generated with the following commands:

```
mkdir -p sandbox/testfiles
pdflatex generate-sandbox.tex
```

where `generate-sandbox.tex` has the following content:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sandbox/build.lua}
#!/usr/bin/env texlua

module = "myclass"

sourcefiles = {"*.cls"}
installfiles = sourcefiles
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sandbox/myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2023/03/24}
  {0.1}
  {
    My~Nice~Class.
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sandbox/testfiles/myclass-test.lvt}
\input{regression-test}
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\START
Foo.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

So far, so good. Now I want to save the output of the test `myclass-test.lvt` to a `.tlg` file:

```
cd sandbox
l3build save myclass-test
```

The output is very verbose:

```
Creating and copying myclass-test.tlg
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 (./ascii.tcx)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22> (./myclass-test.lvt (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3build/regression-test.tex{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}) (./myclass.cls
Document Class: myclass 2023/03/24 v0.1  My\nobreakspace {}Nice\nobreakspace {}Class. 
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file myclass-test.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))

START-TEST-LOG


This is a generated file for the l3build validation system.

Don't change this file in any respect.


[1] (./myclass-test.aux)

END-TEST-LOG

 )</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on myclass-test.pdf (1 page, 13363 bytes).
Transcript written on myclass-test.log.
```

But the content of the `myclass-test.tlg` file looks pretty useless:

```
This is a generated file for the l3build validation system.
  Don't change this file in any respect.
  [1
  ] (myclass-test.aux)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is

```
\START
Foo.
\end{document}
```

so the normalised log is more or less empty, but not necessarily useless,perhaps a future release generates an error and the log becomes non empty and l3build will warn you.

specifically add

```
\AtEndDocument{\oops}
```

to your .cls file.  Now test your new feature with

```
l3build check
```

You will be warned

```
  Check failed with difference files
  - ./build/test/myclass-test.luatex.diff
  - ./build/test/myclass-test.pdftex.diff
  - ./build/test/myclass-test.xetex.diff
```

so the tlg is not useless.

```
*** ./build/test/myclass-test.tlg       Fri Mar 24 22:31:53 2023
--- ./build/test/myclass-test.pdftex.log        Fri Mar 24 22:31:55 2023
***************
*** 1,4 ****
--- 1,13 ----
  This is a generated file for the l3build validation system.
  Don't change this file in any respect.
+ ! Undefined control sequence.
+ \__hook enddocument ->\oops 
+                             \ifpgf@external@grabshipout \pgfutil@ifundefined...
+ l. ...\end{document}
+ The control sequence at the end of the top line
+ of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
+ misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
+ spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
+ and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
  [1
  ] (myclass-test.aux)
```

Usually though you want to put some test output to the log,you can use `\typeout` or `\showoutput` or `regression-test` has specific `\TEST...` commands for making structured log output